# Arduino: wrong digitalRead results from a pullup pin

Tags: programming, button

A button connects `GND` to `PIN` where `PIN` is any digital pin.
I want to catch the moment the button is pressed, so I wrote the following code:

```
void setup () {
    pinMode (PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
    Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop () {
    static bool wasDown = false;
    bool isDown = digitalRead (PIN) == LOW;
    Serial.println (isDown);
    if (isDown && !wasDown) Serial.println ("down!");
    wasDown = isDown;
}
```

While the button is not pressed, everything goes as expected: the output is all zeroes. But when I press it, the following pattern appears:

```
0
0
0
0
<Some other zeroes, about 10 total>
1
down!
<the same number of zeroes>
1
down!
0
...
```

Is it some schematic flaw?

Comment: We have no idea about the hardware involved, but you might want to read about debouncing.

Comment: It is definitely not the case, as the pattern is very regular and stable for a long period

Comment: Also looks like a debouncing problem to me. Could your button have a repeatable bouncing behaviour?

Comment: What happens when you keep the button pressed down - do you see a constant stream of '1'? Can you give us the reference of your button used? @PlasmaHH is most likely right and you might be suffering from debouncing issues.

Comment: 8 buttons connected to different pins could not, I think

Comment: @HervéGrabas no, when I press the button, I see the pattern presented in the question text: N zeroes - one - N zeroes - one - ...

Comment: Schematics and/or picture of setup could help.

Comment: Perhaps try and repeat the experiment with an external resistor?

Comment: @JorenVaes For some reason an external resistor helped... Thanks!

Comment: What output are you expecting/wanting to see?

Comment: @Mazaryk All ones when the button is pressed, all zeroes when it's not. `Serial` just prints the button state continuously. Anyway, the issue was solved by downloading the sketch into another board